# Run an exe from python as a subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to run the following command from python:
`C:\Program Files\Electric Cloud\ElectricCommander\bin\ectool --server server.domain.com login "username" "password"`

The command is not invoked properly using the below code.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
toolLocation = "C:\\Program Files\\Electric Cloud\\ElectricCommander\\bin\\ectool"
parameters = "--server server.domain.com login \"username\" \"password\""
output = Popen([toolLocation, parameters ], stdout=PIPE)
print output.stdout.read()
```

Any idea why it failed?

Comment: if I put `parameters = '--version'`, it would execute that command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing only one paramerter, you need to pass every single parameter as element of a list, eg.:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
toolLocation = "C:\\Program Files\\Electric Cloud\\ElectricCommander\\bin\\ectool"
parameters = ["--server", "server.domain.com", "login", "username", "password"]
output = Popen([toolLocation] + parameters, stdout=PIPE)
print output.stdout.read()
```